# How to find the most recent file in a directory using cpp filesystem

Tags: c++, filesystems, c++17

I'm trying to get the most recent file in a log directory. I'm using c++ and `filesystem` library.

I tried to use a `directory_iterator` from `experimental/filesystem` to iterate on every file in my directory, and, using `std::max_element`, compare the `last_write_time` of each file to have the greater one.

```cpp
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
auto dir_it = fs::directory_iterator(my_path);
auto path = *std::max_element(fs::begin(dir_it), fs::end(dir_it), [](const fs::directory_entry& f1, const fs::directory_entry& f2){
  return fs::last_write_time(f1.path()) < fs::last_write_time(f2.path());
});
```

I expect to get an `fs::directory_entry` object but when I print the path, it's empty.
So I took a look at the compared elements inside my function, and at each step, `f1.path() == f2.path()`, so the output is understandable but I didn't figure out why the compare function doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max_element` requires a forward iterator, while `directory_iterator` is an *input* iterator.

So if you want to do things this way, you'll need to either create a container from the iterators, or manually write a loop yourself.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for this simple mistake.
I finally did a loop by myself.